# Unable to get data from one activity to another activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to the LatLng values from one activity to another, however I'm receiving null values on the other activity.

Activity 1

```
PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteSupportFragment= (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID,Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.NAME));

    autocompleteSupportFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            
           final LatLng latLng= place.getLatLng();
            
           Toast.makeText(searchActivity.this, "Latitude"+latLng.latitude+ "" +"Longitude"+latLng.longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //
              lat1 = latLng.latitude;
              long1 = latLng.longitude;
            Intent intent1= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), shortestRouteActivity.class);

            intent1.putExtra("lat1",lat1 ); intent1.putExtra("long1",long1);

            Log.i("Place Coordinates: " ,"Latitude :"+latLng.latitude+ "" +"Longitude :"+latLng.longitude);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i( "An error occurred: " , ""+status);
        }
    });
```

Activity 2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shortest_route);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    double lat1 = bundle.getDouble("lat1");
    double long1 = bundle.getDouble("long1");


    Log.i("Lat 1 and Long 1 =", lat1 + " : " +long1);

}
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.os.BaseBundle.getDouble(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
```

I have tried all the other ways to the get the values but still unable to do so.

Any-kind of help is appreciated! Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

How are u initializing the 2nd activity? Where is your

```
startActivity(intent1);
```

Maybe you are creating the 2nd activity before getting those values.

Comment: Yes, you have to add this line after creating the Intent object and ONLY after that. You might have added this code somewhere else, which is called before these values are set.

Comment: I'm really sorry , i must have missed to include it in my question while making this post, i do have a startActivity(intent1); in my code , yet still receiving nullpointerException.

Comment: Hey, i figured it out, i was getting the values as 0.0 , i had to change the"double lat1 = bundle.getDouble("lat1");" to "double lat1 = Double.valueOf(bundle.getString("lat1"));"